# Trying to find Total Sales & Total Cost of 3 different Countries cars

Tags: python, jupyter

Update: Below is the excel file link.

I am brand new to Python and was doing this graph but I am stuck, I am trying to show a horizontal bar graph with 3 different countries, spain, germany, switzerland and trying to show the the total sales and total costs. I keep getting an error but not sure If my formula is correct If you could please take a look.

Error I get is below. If someone could please assist!

line 33
total.plot('CountryMake', ['Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price'], kind='barh')
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import pandas as pd

sales= pd.read_excel('Simplified Car Sales Data.xlsx')

spa= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Spain']

spa_totals = spa.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
spa_count = spa.count(axis=0)

spa_total_sale_price = round(spa_totals) ['SalePrice']
spa_total_cost_price = round(spa_totals) ['CostPrice']

swi= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Switzerland']

swi_totals = spa.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
swi_count = spa.count(axis=0)

swi_total_sale_price = round(swi_totals) ['SalePrice']
swi_total_cost_price = round(swi_totals) ['CostPrice']

ger= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Germany']

ger_totals = ger.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
ger_count = ger.count(axis=0)

ger_total_sale_price = round(ger_totals) ['SalePrice']
ger_total_cost_price = round(ger_totals) ['CostPrice']

totals = pd.DataFrame([('Spain',spa_tot_sale_price, spa_tot_cost_price),
                         ('Switzerland', swi_tot_sale_price,swi_tot_cost_price),
                         ('Germany', ger_tot_sale_price,ger_tot_cost_price),
                     columns ['CountryName', 'Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price']
total.plot('CountryMake', ['Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price'], kind='barh')


Error I get is below. If someone could please assist!

File "C:\Users\danac\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16616\2535154149.py", line 33
    total.plot('CountryMake', ['Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price'], kind='barh')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Could you include an extract from the excel file?

Comment: Make CountryName SalePrice CostPrice TotalDiscount DeliveryCharge SpareParts LaborCost Model Color

Comment: Update: Below is the link of the data file.

Comment: I updated my answer. It works with your file. My advice still remains to use an IDE. The issues were due to incorrect naming and brackets. Both are addressed by IDEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you defined `total` in this part of the code. So, you may need to do `totals.plot`. You also didn't close the brackets.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sales= pd.read_excel('Simplified Car Sales Data.xlsx')

spa= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Spain']

spa_totals = spa.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
spa_count = spa.count(axis=0)

spa_total_sale_price = round(spa_totals) ['SalePrice']
spa_total_cost_price = round(spa_totals) ['CostPrice']

swi= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Switzerland']

swi_totals = spa.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
swi_count = spa.count(axis=0)

swi_total_sale_price = round(swi_totals) ['SalePrice']
swi_total_cost_price = round(swi_totals) ['CostPrice']

ger= sales[sales['CountryName'] == 'Germany']

ger_totals = ger.sum(axis=0, numeric_only = True)
ger_count = ger.count(axis=0)

ger_total_sale_price = round(ger_totals) ['SalePrice']
ger_total_cost_price = round(ger_totals) ['CostPrice']

totals = pd.DataFrame([('Spain',spa_total_sale_price, spa_total_cost_price),
                         ('Switzerland', swi_total_sale_price,swi_total_cost_price),
                         ('Germany', ger_total_sale_price,ger_total_cost_price)],
                     columns=['CountryName', 'Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price'])
totals.plot('CountryName', ['Total Sales Price', 'Total Cost Price'], kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

This should work, although I don't guarantee given that I don't have your data.
P.S.
Try to use IDEs. It will be easier that way